# Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply c# EF 5

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, where-clause

I’m getting the following exception from EF 5:
Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

Here is my Query:

```
String username = “test”;
IEnumerable<Int32> roles;
IEnumerable<Int32> applications;

cnx.Users.Where ( it =>
( userName != null ?  it.name = = userName : true )  &&
( !roles.Any () || roles.Contains ( it.role_id ) ) &&
( ! applications.Any () || applications.Contains ( it.application_id ) ) )
               .Count ();
```

Users is a simple table. 
Roles and applications are both typeof IEnumerable and can be empty.

How can I change my query, that it will work in EF 5 (.Net 4.0)?

Comment: use the `{ }` button on the toolbar.

Comment: I don't think you need `Any` check, because you already have `Contains` on the same navigation property. You should try removing it.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: Have a sharp look: There is a bang before the `Any`, meaning: The list should be empty or contain the ID. If only the `Contains` would be there, the result would be `false` instead of `true` for an empty list.

Comment: Yes that’s the reason why I use an Any there… no date in the collections means no filtering of the database records.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me it looks like `userName`, `roles` and `applications` are parameters to the query, i.e. the data comes from your application and not from the database. In that case, I would write the query like this:

```
IQueryable<User> query = cnt.Users;
if(userName != null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.name == userName)
if(roles.Any())
    query = query.Where(x => roles.Contains(x.role_id));
if(applications.Any())
    query = query.Where(x => applications.Contains(x.application_id))

var result = query.Count();
```

This is a lot more readable and doesn't include unnecessary clutter into the resulting query.

Please note that `roles` and `applications` must not represent the unexecuted result of another query.
With "unexecuted result", I mean the following:

```
IEnumerable<Role> roles = context.Roles.Where(x => x = y);
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much. 
Just one detail, is there no good way to create the same query only using linq & lambda?

Comment: @user1320170: Why would you want to do that? It should be your goal to make the queries you send as simple as possible.

Comment: I ‘don’t want to change the query generated by EF, I just want to use only linq & lambda (similar to the code posted in my question) … if there is a way to do this?
Btw. The reason why I want to use “only” linq & lambda is, that I think it’s more readable.

Comment: @user1320170: While readability certainly is subjective, the code you have is a lot less readable than the code proposed by me, because in the case of your code, the brain needs to process a lot more information in one go: parentheses, the ternary operator, logical operators etc. And as you can see by MarcinJuraszek's comment on your question, it is harder to understand, because of that. Your attempt is actually the only way I can think of to write it all in one lambda expression and if that doesn't work, you need to use an approach similar to mine.

Comment: Haha your right… readability is very subjective. But anyway thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, are iterate over the records getting the another ones and aggregate to an final list.

It's not fastest, not beauty, but will solve.