# Simplifying Linq expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm using this Linq Expression in my application which is using Entity Framework 5

```
var managers =
    UnitOfWork.UserRepository.Get(
      u => userAccounts.All(ua => u.Permissions.Any(uap => 
      ((uap.AccountId == ua || uap.PermissionId == 1) && uap.Config == "SET")))
      && (user.IsGenericUser || u.StageId== user.StageId));
```

Here `useraccounts` is a `List<int>` object.

But this is throwing exception

> Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

How can I simplify this expression to avoid such an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a SQL procedure / view to accomplish this. EF encourages this kind of strategy however is (imo) usually less performant. The procedure / view can then be executed via your context.

Answer (score 0):

I googled this exception and found these similar questions that might be helpful: [Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14163390/some-part-of-your-sql-statement-is-nested-too-deeply-rewrite-the-query-or-break)

[Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply c# EF 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002732/some-part-of-your-sql-statement-is-nested-too-deeply-c-sharp-ef-5)

Comment: I haven't used the All() method, but maybe that's part of the problem. Instead of doing All(conditions), could you maybe do an Any(!condition) instead to have the same logical result?